# Exam 70-484 (Essentials of developing Windows Store apps) - App/Nav bar in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, navigation, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm going to take [70-484](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam-70-484.aspx) exam (Essentials of developing Windows Store apps using C#) and as I can see it will change a bit on November 18 to accomodate Windows 8.1. One of the changes is they no longer speak of *app bars* but instead of *app/nav bars* - is it just a new terminology for the same thing or is there some new concept behind it? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, these are the same things from the different frameworks:
[XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbar.aspx) and [WinJS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301893.aspx). And I have found an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn342878.aspx) where both of them are used in the Windows Store application. The changes might be reffered to the fact that both frameworks can be used to achieve the same things.